# How to return unique values from an aggregate function calculated field?

Tags: sql

I'm currently a beginner learning SQL and am trying to write a query for a project that retrieves information from a SALESMAN table and the total they have made from a PRODUCT table. The two tables are seperated by other tables and I'm not sure what I need to specify for it to produce the result I want.

My current code:

```sql
SELECT SALES_ID, SUM(QUANTITY*PRICE) As Total 
FROM SALESMAN, PRODUCT 
GROUP BY SALES_ID
```

Returns:

| SALES_ID | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 10006 | 1600 |
| 10007 | 1600 |
| 10008 | 1600 |
| 10009 | 1600 |

I want it to return as this:

| SALES_ID | Total |
| --- | --- |
| 10006 | 255 |
| 10007 | 128 |
| 10008 | 1072 |
| 10009 | 78 |

Any tips or advice would be very appreciated.

Comment: A "Cartesian product" is created by using commas in the from clause, to avoid this, learn to use `inner join` or `left join` style syntax  - while it ca be confusing initially - it will help you avoid problems like the one you describe above. i.e. **don't use** `from table1, table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your result is strange because you don't specify a join condition. Therefore you create a [cartesian product](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm). For keeping it short here, please refer to the link.

To fix your problem you need to join the rows only when the Sales_ID is the same in both tables.

Since you don't provide the source data I can't test my code, but I believe the following will solve your problem.

```
SELECT 
    SALES_ID,
    SUM(QUANTITY * PRICE) AS Total 
FROM 
    SALESMAN AS L
LEFT JOIN
    PRODUCT AS R1 ON L.Sales_ID = R1.Sales_ID
GROUP BY 
    SALES_ID
```

Comment: Because all the rows are matched up and because OP is a beginner it might be worth noting that an inner join is sufficient here.